# Ruby app only works when Passenger is "disabled"

Tags: ruby, apache2, sinatra, passenger

I have deployed a Sinatra application on an Ubuntu server using Apache and Passenger. Through some trial and error, I realize the app only works when the passenger module is disabled.

```
$ a2dismod passenger
```

After an Apache restart, the app runs as expected.

If I re-enable the module...

```
$ a2enmod passenger
```

...I see this warning upon Apache restart:

```
[warn] module passenger_module is already loaded, skipping
```

and the app stops working. Apache responds, serving the contents of the vhost's document root, but is not recognized by Passenger.

I'm glad my app works, but I'm not sure how to explain the reversed effect of enabling/disabling the passenger module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same problem: if you follow passenger installing instruction with this version of Apache you may actually tell Apache to load passenger twice.

Before adding the 3 famous lines to your Apache configuration file:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/…/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290/ruby
```

Check the configuration file apache2.conf for lines like these:

```
# Include module configuration:
Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.load
Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.conf
```

If these lines do exists it means that on start your Apache server will include every *.conf and *.load file from /mods-available to /mods-enabled and than load them.

So if you run in the concerning warning message it means you are loading passenger module twice!

You can take advantage of this Apache feature going to /mods-available, looking for passenger.conf and passenger.load files and edit them instead of apache2.conf.

The ‘LoadModule passenger_module’ line goes into passenger.load, while the other 2 ‘PassengerRoot’ and ‘PassengerRuby’ lines go into passenger.conf.

Then restart your server and you’ll be fine.

More about this issue here: http://www.duccioarmenise.net/ruby-on-rails/warn-module-passenger_module-is-already-loaded/

Comment: Apache will definitly not copy and configuration files on startup. Instead, you are supposed to create symlinks in `mods-available` pointing to files in `mods-available`. There are the two helper scripts `a2enmod` and `a2dismod` which do exactly that.

Comment: You're right, I used the wrong word, just corrected. I guess you wanted to say _"...to create symlinks in `mods-enabled` pointing to files in `mods-available`."_.

Answer (score 0):

This most likely means you've specified 'LoadModule passenger_module ...' twice. The first entry is somewhere not in passenger.conf, the second entry is in passenger.conf.

Comment: I include the LoadModule directive in a site-specific Apache config file. It must be the second occurrence, but when I remove it the remaining Passenger-related directives in the config file are not recognized. For example, PassengerRoot, PassengerRuby, PassengerDefaultUser, RackEnv now result in a syntax error when restarting Apache.

Comment: That's because Phusion Passenger is now not loaded at all, or loaded after you set the Passenger options. You must ensure that 1) Phusion Passenger is loaded only once  and 2) that the Passenger options are specified after the LoadModule.